# Send image as a respose stream or point to image on file share with JSON response

Tags: c#, performance, rest, architecture, image-processing

I wonder about the pros and cons using these different techniques.

Sending an image as a respose stream will result in just one request to the server, but will take more processing power for the Service.

Compared to saving the image on a file share and sending an url back to the client, and letting the client request the image directly on a file share.

What strategy would you recommend, this service will have a huge amount of requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think the greatest way is sending directly an Image, because :

- there is only one request
- it's no manipulate the hard disk
- the image in RAM is less used

For the other way, i see many cons :

- you use the hard drive two times (write and read)
- your server must treat two requests
- the image in RAM is used to write, to read and to send

You must to do some tests, but i think sending directly image is at instant more greedy, but on total, the more greedy is the saved image solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will still need to save the image to disc since it will take a lot of time to process the image before sending it back to the client. I just want to process the image once, next time it is requested it will be available on disc.

Comment: @Flatron I suggest map drive disc its better for write and read

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on the processing need for your image.

If your image is specifically processing for each request, you'll need to create a new image on the fly each time. In this case, there is no reason to save your file and share it in a link.

If your image will be reused by other requests, then you could consider both. The streaming overhead is not a complete tricky point but the overhead exists:

- processing overhead
- request processed by managed code
- all httpmodules/handlers called by each request
- even if cached by iis (dynamic caching), streaming is more costly than sending a file.
- you'll have difficulties in sharing this file across multiple servers -> local cache only (and if you have to pay a distributed cache access it's not relevant any more), plus, a file should be accessed through a cdn

And more, for performance reasons, you should want to free for other requests your http request from processing as soon as possible, then getting a static file image is another working network task on the browser.

To resume, consider your usage and the lifetime cycle of your image data.